# Cocoa Bindings "Selection" not changing when table rows clicked

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder, xcode5, cocoa-bindings

Hello there: I have in essence a master-detail application with one master view-based NSTable view and two detail views. My master NSTable loads and displays data from a Managed Object Context correctly. One of my detail views should load the image of the object in selected table row. But here is my problem that no one else on the Internet seems to have:

My "selection" object isn't changing. I did bind the the value of image view on my detail view to the Array Controller, and controller key is: "selection", model key is "image". The image view *only* loads the first object's image in the table, and if I click/select on other rows, the image isn't changing. So it seems like "selection" object is always the first object. Since this is all done in Interface Builder, I don't have any code to show, sorry.

Does anyone know what is going on? Why is the "selection" object always the first in the table? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind the NSTableView’s selection to the NSArrayController’s, like so:

[image]

Comment: Oh boy, thank you so much! Is this documented? I didn't seem to find it on Apple's documentation, really should think harder next time, haha.

Comment: I haven’t read the docs in years, but I’d assume it’s in some “master detail” tutorial somewhere.